# Making countdown timer

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to make a countdown timer!

Here is the timer code I tried:

```
class WorkingWithTimer
        {
            public static int input()
            {
                int numberOfSeconds;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many seconds would you like the test to be? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfSeconds);
                } while (numberOfSeconds % 10 != 0);
                return numberOfSeconds;  
            } 
            
            public static void CountTimer(object time)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"TimeLeft: {time}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int numberOfSeconds = input();
                Timer t = new Timer(CountTimer, numberOfSeconds, 1, 1000);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                t.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

At the moment my code prints this in the console:
[image]

However, I want my code to countdown the seconds and only use one line in output.

---

## Update

I am trying to make a countdown timer!

Here is the timer code I tried:

```
class WorkingWithTimer
        {
            public static int input()
            {
                int numberOfSeconds;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many seconds would you like the test to be? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfSeconds);
                } while (numberOfSeconds % 10 != 0);
                return numberOfSeconds;  
            } 
            
            public static void CountTimer(object time)
            {
                var x = (int[])time;
                x[0]--;
                Console.WriteLine($"TimeLeft: {x[0]}");
            }
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] numberOfSeconds = new int[1];
                numberOfSeconds[0] = input();
                Timer t = new Timer(CountTimer, numberOfSeconds, 1, 1000);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                t.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

At the moment my code prints this in the console:
[image].

However, I want my code to countdown without creating a newline, like the 10 changes into a 9 on the first line and so on.

Comment: One line in the console output?

Comment: @Marlonchosky yes

Comment: @danyal51 what do you mean by one line in the console output?

Comment: @CDS like the 30 turns into 29 without creating a newline when I run the code

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @CaiusJard No, this is a small part of a maths game I am creating.

Comment: Please point out in your code *where* you decrement the input 30, so that it becomes 29, 28, 27...

Comment: @danyal51 - Please don't edit your question so that it invalidates your original one. You have two choices - leave the question alone and post a completely new question OR append the new information to the bottom of the existing question. I've done the latter for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what I've deduced about that custom Timer class you're using is correct, it:

- has a constructor that takes a delegate that shall be called every interval
- takes an object from you and passes it back to you every time it ticks
- not sure what the 1 is for, avoid magic numbers in your code
- guessing that 1000 is the interval in milliseconds. Again, avoid using plain numbers in your code without a comment or a constant var with a name
- operates synchronously out of its constructor without ever being started

Because it provides the same object back to you all the time you'll need to change your code a little so the object being passed is not a value type; if you don't then you'll decrement the int in the CountTimer but nothing will change because you'll not be modifying the data pointed to by the original reference. You probably can't just add a ref keyword because the custom timer won't be programmed to call with it. So, let's tweak it so we are passing an int array instead:

```
        public static void CountTimer(object time)
        {
            var x = (int[])time;
            x[0]--;
            Console.WriteLine($"TimeLeft: {x[0]}");
            //Thread.Sleep(1000); you don't need to sleep for a second; it will make your timer count every two seconds!
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numberOfSeconds = new int[1];
            numberOfSeconds[0] = input();
            Timer t = new Timer(CountTimer, numberOfSeconds, 1, 1000);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            t.Dispose();
        }
```

As noted, all this hinges on your Timer class there being some custom one that takes the name of a method to call every x milliseconds and keeps providing it with the same object. Nowhere decremented the int time you have so it just said 30 over and again. We can't just cast `time` as you had it, to an int and decrement it because it won't cause the original int held by the Timer to change. If instead we make it so that the object the Timer holds is an int array, then the array object itself never changes, but the value stored in the first slot can be decremented

FWIW, I think this is quite a complex way to just create a countdown timer, and it's also blocking the user from doing anything else. If that suits your game then fine, but if you're expecting them to make a move within 30 seconds I think you'll run into trouble with this Timer class you're using

Comment: Nice. I like the use of a single element array to pass as the state.

Comment: How would I do it if I need to get them to answer within the time?

Comment: @danyal51 - Answer what? How many seconds the timer should be?

Comment: @Enigmativity answer a few maths question within the time limit as this is a small part of a maths game

Comment: Doing it as a console app is quite hard work; save yourself the hassle and create a Windows UI app. Console app is a hassle because you need to stop the app from ending, and that is classically done with a ReadLine that blocks waiting for user input, which then means your timer stops. You could do it as the DateTime the user answers minus the DateTime the question was asked but you will still struggle to make "user interface" that prints the timer and also asks a user for input without one overwriting the other. Scrap what you have and make a GUI app

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a `System.Threading.Timer` and a Console App you're going to need to have a way of telling the Console App to wait around until your timer is finished. Calling `Thread.Sleep(1000);` won't cut it - especially since you are waiting at least 10 seconds.

The simple way to make the Console App to wait is to use a `AutoResetEvent`.

```
private static AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Now you can call `_autoResetEvent.WaitOne();` in your `Main` method and it will wait until you call `_autoResetEvent.Set();` in your `CountTimer` method.

Now, with a `System.Threading.Timer` you can pass in state when you construct the timer, but that state doesn't update, so you're going to need to add another field to keep track of the number of seconds that have ticked by.

```
private static int _numberOfSeconds = 0;
```

Also, when you do anything with time in the framework and you have the choice between passing an `int` or using a `TimeSpan` you should always choose `TimeSpan` as this makes your code far more readable.

Your `Main` & `CountTimer` methods can now look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _numberOfSeconds = input();
    using (var t = new Timer(CountTimer, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(1000); No Need To Sleep Here!
        _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
    _autoResetEvent.Dispose();
}

public static void CountTimer(object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"TimeLeft: {_numberOfSeconds--}");
    //Thread.Sleep(1000); No Need To Sleep Here!
    if (_numberOfSeconds < 0)
    {
        _autoResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Note that I pass `null` in as the state for the `Timer` as there was no real state for sample code.

The output that I get when I run this code with an input of `10` is this:

```
How many seconds would you like the test to be? Please type a number divisible by 10!
TimeLeft: 10
TimeLeft: 9
TimeLeft: 8
TimeLeft: 7
TimeLeft: 6
TimeLeft: 5
TimeLeft: 4
TimeLeft: 3
TimeLeft: 2
TimeLeft: 1
TimeLeft: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You should review [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netcore-3.1) for more information. Basically, you could do this:

```
class StatusChecker {
    private int numberOfSecondsLeft;

    public StatusChecker(int numberOfSecondsLeft) {
        this.numberOfSecondsLeft = numberOfSecondsLeft;
    }

    public void CountDown(object state) {
        Console.Write($"{this.numberOfSecondsLeft},");

        var autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)state;
        if (--this.numberOfSecondsLeft == 0) {
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var numberOfSeconds = input();
        var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var checker = new StatusChecker(numberOfSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Time left:");
        var t = new Timer(checker.CountDown, autoEvent, 0, 1000);
        autoEvent.WaitOne();
        t.Dispose();
    }

    public static int input() {
        int numberOfSeconds;
        do {
            Console.WriteLine("How many seconds would you like the test to be? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfSeconds);
        } while (numberOfSeconds % 10 != 0);
        return numberOfSeconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to an external site and dump a bunch of code. Please explain your answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity The external site is from the official Microsoft documentation. They explain the topic and class in depth.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Please don't link to an external site (even if it is the official Microsoft documentation). Your answer should be self contained and links should only be there to support content you have written in your answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think is redundant  to explain something that the official documentation explains clearly and there is nothing than add to the explanation.

Comment: The SO community doesn't think it is redundant. Please read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Enigmativity In this case the answer doesn't only contains just links, also contains a solution for the problem. The code is explaining in the official documentation of Microsoft, and the code that I changed from the documentation to adapt to the question is no complex. If an explanation is needed, the author can ask for the exact point of interest.